# Best method to return multiple views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
var myView: some View {
    Group {
        Text("Hello")
        Text("Bye")
    }
}
```

```
@ViewBuilder var myView: some View {
    Text("Hello")
    Text("Bye")
}
```

Should I use a `Group` or `@ViewBuilder`, are there any advantages in using one over the other in terms of performance and customizability? If not, is there a convention in place to use one rather than the other?

Comment: Here is one article on HackingWithSwift which talks about different ways of returning views. Maybe you can find it useful. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-return-different-view-types

Comment: And [here](https://holyswift.app/three-ways-to-refactor-massive-swiftui-views/) is another good articles that is actually about refactoring views but goes through the above variants and some more

Answer (score -1):

Personally I think that you shouldn't do both, if you need two vertically aligned Text views then just wrap them in VStack (or whatever you need) and make a component for flexibility. It will help with debug and will make your entire codebase more readable. Just write something like that and properly name it.

```
struct TwoTextViews: some View {
    @Binding var firstLabelText: String
    @Binding var secondLabelText: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(firstLabelText)
            Text(secondLabelText)
        }
    }
}
```

Don't really get the situation when you should return a list of separate views instead of them wrapped into some container.

Comment: Using a @ViewBuilder allows you to return multiple views for a List. If you had group them together in a VStack they would render as a single List cell.